# How to change the values of table with column name

Tags: r, data.table

Following code gave me data table

```
library(RMySQL)
library(reshape)
library(philentropy)
library(distances)
mydb = dbConnect(MySQL(), user='root', password='root', dbname='test_db', host='127.0.0.1')
rs = dbSendQuery(mydb,'select   cv.entity_id,cv.attribute_id, cv.value/1000 as value from   test_1 cv limit 100')
data = fetch(rs,n=-1)
pivotedData = cast(data,entity_id ~ attribute_id) 
distCalcNew = distances(pivotedData,id_variable='entity_id') 
nns <- nearest_neighbor_search(distCalcNew,k=3)
nnsdt <- data.table(nns)
```

I have a data table in R as follows, data points indicates column indices

```
    8456 8720 5780
1:    1    2    3
2:    3    3    2
3:    2    1    1
```

Is it possible to get the following?

```
    8456 8720 5780
1:  8456 8720 5780
2:  5780 5780 8720
3:  8720 8456 8456
```

Sorry, I'm new to R

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another idea,

```
m1 <- matrix(names(x)[unlist(x)], ncol = ncol(x))

#tidy up
setNames(data.frame(m1), names(x))
#  8456 8720 5780
#1 8456 8720 5780
#2 5780 5780 8720
#3 8720 8456 8456
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lapply` to the DataFrame `df`, so that based on the value, it will retrive the column name in that index

```
df[] <-  lapply(df, function(x) {
    return(colnames(df)[x])
})
```

Comment: Can you also post the code for data initialization?

Comment: Edited based on your example

Answer (score 1):

Using *lapply*, but there must be a better "data.table-way":

```
library(data.table)

x <- fread("8456 8720 5780
1    2    3
3    3    2
2    1    1", header = TRUE)


as.data.table(lapply(x, function(i) as.integer(colnames(x)[ i ])))
#    8456 8720 5780
# 1: 8456 8720 5780
# 2: 5780 5780 8720
# 3: 8720 8456 8456
```

Comment: I don't have string instead a data table to begin with